# Join two Rects in Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

I'm trying to get into Core Graphics.
A the Moment I'm trying to draw a certain shape out of 2 rects. Now I want to join those booth to work with gradient and color functions. I'm not sure if there even is a way.
Here is a Picture:
[image: Here is a picture]

Here are my Code Snippets:

```
-(void)drawRoundedRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y+45, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height-45);

    CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width-80, self.bounds.origin.y+25, 80, 50);


    CGPathRef roundedRectPath1 = [self newPathForRoundedRect:frame1 radius:15];
    CGPathRef roundedRectPath2 = [self newPathForRoundedRect:frame2 radius:11];
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 200, 200, 200, 0.5);


    CGContextAddPath(ctx, roundedRectPath1);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);

    CGPathRelease(roundedRectPath1);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, roundedRectPath2);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
    CGPathRelease(roundedRectPath2);


}

-(CGPathRef) newPathForRoundedRect:(CGRect)rect radius:(CGFloat)radius
{

    CGMutablePathRef retPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGRect innerRect = CGRectInset(rect, radius, radius);

    CGFloat inside_right = innerRect.origin.x + innerRect.size.width;
    CGFloat outside_right = rect.origin.x + rect.size.width;
    CGFloat inside_bottom = innerRect.origin.y + innerRect.size.height;
    CGFloat outside_bottom = rect.origin.y + rect.size.height;

    CGFloat inside_top = innerRect.origin.y;
    CGFloat outside_top = rect.origin.y;
    CGFloat outside_left = rect.origin.x;

    CGPathMoveToPoint(retPath, NULL, innerRect.origin.x, outside_top);

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(retPath, NULL, inside_right, outside_top);
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(retPath, NULL, outside_right, outside_top, outside_right, inside_top, radius);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(retPath, NULL, outside_right, inside_bottom);
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(retPath, NULL,  outside_right, outside_bottom, inside_right, outside_bottom, radius);

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(retPath, NULL, innerRect.origin.x, outside_bottom);
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(retPath, NULL,  outside_left, outside_bottom, outside_left, inside_bottom, radius);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(retPath, NULL, outside_left, inside_top);
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(retPath, NULL,  outside_left, outside_top, innerRect.origin.x, outside_top, radius);

    CGPathCloseSubpath(retPath);

    return retPath;
}
```

Comment: Does CGContextAddPath work?  The docs say it adds all subpaths of the given path to the current one.  So calling CGContextAddPath twice before doing FillPath maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing way too much work here.  Just use UIBezierPath's `+bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cornerRadius:` and `– appendPath:`  methods.

```
CGRect rect1, rect2;
CGFloat radius;

  // fill in the values you want for the rects and the radius
UIBezierPath *result = 
    [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: rect1 cornerRadius:radius];
[result appendPath: 
    [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: rect2 cornerRadius:radius];

 // result is now a path comprising both of the roundrects.  You can fill it with a gradient like any other path.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some options:

1. Construct a new path that forms the union of the two separate paths without intersections. Core Graphics would not help you with this approach, it does not provide boolean path operations.
2. Use a transparency layer to draw both shapes (one after each other). This would fix the overlapping area but it wouldn't work with gradients.
3. Create a bitmap context to create a mask. Draw both shapes into the mask. Then clip to the mask in your original context and draw a rect over the bounding box of your shape.